# Charfield must match with another Charfield Django form validation

Tags: django, django-forms

Hello I am unable to find documentation about a validation that a charfield  must match with another charfield

For instance I want a validation that new_password must match with confirm_new_password:

```
class ChangePassword(forms.Form):
    new_password = forms.CharField(label='New Password', max_length=100, error_messages={'required': 'New password is required'}, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    confirm_new_password = forms.CharField(label='Confirm New Password', max_length=100, error_messages={'required': 'Confirm New password is required'}, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#charfield

It seems the main ones are `required, max_length, min_length`?

Comment: [Cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

Comment: Its one of the first headings under form validation.

Comment: Note that Django comes with built in authentication [views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#built-in-auth-views) and [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#built-in-auth-forms) which handle changing passwords. Use these rather than writing your own.

Answer (score -1):

To perform custom form validation, you will need to override the clean() function like so:

```
class ChangePassword(forms.Form):
    new_password = forms.CharField(label='New Password', max_length=100, error_messages={'required': 'New password is required'}, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    confirm_new_password = forms.CharField(label='Confirm New Password', max_length=100, error_messages={'required': 'Confirm New password is required'}, widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    def clean(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data['new_password']
        confirm_password = self.cleaned_data['confirm_new_password']
        if password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Your passwords do not match!')
```

Comment: If the user does not enter a value for one of the fields, this example will give a `KeyError`. The docs that Sayse linked to show how to do this correctly.

Comment: Correct, thanks for your response. This was just for examples sake to solve the main problem highlighted.